# Flutter list is not rebuilt and the new item has not appeared

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart

hi i m using the rest API to bring data from the data base and when i make a change in the data base i want it so if i Go to the other screen and  Pop to the previous screen i want the get request from the api to re build the list and the new items should appear but at the moment it dosen't refresh so only the old list appears any help and thank you

````
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:az/Actifs.dart';
import 'package:az/SR_Details.dart';
import 'package:az/main.dart';
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'class/sr.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DataFromAPI(),
    );
  }
}

class DataFromAPI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataFromAPIState createState() => _DataFromAPIState();
}

List<Sr> _MyAllData=[];
List<Sr> _SrForDsiplay=[];
Map<String, Color>  map={
"QUEUED":Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 136, 0),
"CLOSED":Colors.grey,
"Rejeced":Colors.red,
"INPROG":Colors.green,
"PENDING":Colors.blue,
"RESOLVED":Colors.green,
"NEW":Colors.blue,
};
Map<String, String>  map1={
"1":"Urgent",
"2":"High",
"3":"Medium",
"4":"Low",
};
Map<String, Color>  map3={
"Urgent":Colors.red,
"High":Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 139, 131),
"Medium":Colors.blue,
"Low":Colors.green,
"null":Colors.grey,
};
class _DataFromAPIState extends State<DataFromAPI> {
String title_string = "Liste des SR";
  @override
  void initState() {
    loadData().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _MyAllData.addAll(value);   
        _SrForDsiplay=_MyAllData;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<Sr>> loadData() async {
    try {
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
          'http://192.168.1.59:9080/maxrest/rest/mbo/sr/?_lid=maxadmin&_lpwd=maxadmin&_format=json'));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonBody = json.decode(response.body);
        Demandes data = Demandes.fromJson(jsonBody);
        final srAttributes = data.srMboSet.sr;
                title_string='Liste des SR : ${srAttributes.length.toString()}';  

        return srAttributes;
       }
       } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e.toString());
    }
    throw Exception("");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner:false,
      home: new Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false ,
  appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title_string),
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back), onPressed: () {  Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home())); },
             ),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<List<Sr>?>(
          future: loadData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {  
            if (!(_MyAllData.isNotEmpty)) {
              return SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.3,
          child: Center(
           child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
           );
            } else { return ListView(
              children: <Widget>[Padding(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
             child: TextField(
               decoration:
               InputDecoration(icon: Icon(Icons.search), hintText: "Enter id or description"),
             onChanged: (text) {
             text=text.toLowerCase();
             setState(() {
             _SrForDsiplay =_MyAllData.where((srAttributes) {
             var srDescription = srAttributes.attributes.description!.content.toString().toLowerCase();
             var srID= srAttributes.attributes.ticketid.content.toString();
             return srDescription.contains(text) || srID.contains(text); 
              }).toList();
              title_string='Liste des SR : ${_SrForDsiplay.length.toString()}';
             print(title_string);
             }
             );
             },
             ),
             ),
               new ListView.builder(scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: _SrForDsiplay.length,
                itemBuilder: ((_, index) {
                  return
                        new ListTile(
                          title: new Card(
                            margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 2.0, horizontal: 8.0),
                            elevation: 10,
                            child: new ListTile(
                              title: new Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(2.0)),
                                  Row(children :[
                                  Container(
                                   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                     border: Border.all(
                                     color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                                    ),
                                    color: map['${_SrForDsiplay[index].attributes.status.content}'],
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                   ),
                                   child:Text('  ${_SrForDsiplay[index].attributes.status.content}  '),
                                  ),
                                    Container(child: Text('  '),),
                                   Container(
                                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border.all(
                                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                                     ),
                                    color: map3[map1['${_SrForDsiplay[index].attributes.reportedpriority?.content}']],
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                     ),
                                    child:Text( map1['${_SrForDsiplay[index].attributes.reportedpriority?.content}'] ?? " null "),
                                    ),
                                   ],
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox( 
                                     height: 8,
                                     ),
                                     Row(children: <Widget>[
                                      Expanded( child: Container(child: Text('${_SrForDsiplay[index].attributes.description?.content}',style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),),),),
                                       Expanded(child: Container(child:Text( '  ${_SrForDsiplay[index].attributes.ticketid.content}',style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),)))
                                     ],),
                                      new Divider(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 110, 109, 109),
                                     ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Reported : ${DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd().format(DateTime.parse('${_SrForDsiplay[index].attributes.statusdate.content}' ))}' ,
                                 style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                                    ),
                                  new Text(
                                      'Reported by  : ${_SrForDsiplay[index].attributes.reportedby?.content}',style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                                  ),
                                  Row(children: [new Image(image: AssetImage('assets/courroi.png'), width: 20),
                                      Text(
                                      '${_SrForDsiplay[index].attributes.assetnum?.content}'),], ),
                                  Row(children: [new Image(image: AssetImage('assets/emp.png'), width: 20),
                                      Text(
                                      '${_SrForDsiplay[index].attributes.assetsiteid?.content}'),], ) ,
                                       Divider(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 110, 109, 109),
                                     ),
                                     Row(children:[
                                      Expanded(child: Badge(            
                                        position: BadgePosition.topEnd(top: -8, end: 20),
                                        badgeColor: Colors.grey,
                                        badgeContent: Text('1'),
                                        child :IconButton(icon :Icon(Icons.file_present_rounded),  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),

                                        onPressed: () {
                                        },),
                                      )
                                        ),
                                      Expanded(child: IconButton ( 
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.file_copy),
                                        onPressed: () {  }, 
                                        ),),
                                      Expanded(child:  IconButton(onPressed:() {  
                                      }, icon: Icon(Icons.delete))  )
                                        ],)
                                ],  
                              ),
                              trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded),
                              
                            ),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
        /*  Navigator.push(
          context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>SRDetail()),
  );*/
                    }
                  );
                 }
                ),
               )
              ]
             );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: why are you calling loadData() in both initState and futurebuilder?

Comment: are you try to refresh your screen after pop from SRDetail?

Comment: i tried to exit the page and enter again and it s not refreshing

Answer (score 0):

By the way, this is not good to call `loadData()` function in `initState` and `Future.builder()` at the same time.

Moreover, the common usage of `Future` is to handle `HTTP` calls. What you can listen to on a `Future` is its state. Whether it's done, finished with success, or had an error. But that's it.

A `Future` can't listen to a variable change. It's a one-time response. Instead, you'll need to use a `Stream`.